# Test Loss plateau fast in Convolutional Neural Net

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, convolution, pytorch

I have a 10k dataset of 1 channel 100X100pixels images with 31 classes.
I set up a CNN with 3 convolution layers each followed by a batchnorm and a 2d pooling. I tried out several combinations of learning step size and batch size, but my loss on the test set (crossentropy) always plateau at the same level.

Here's my model:

```
class myCNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # conv2d( 1-in channels, 2-out channels, 3-kernel size, padding=0, bias=True)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5, padding=2)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5, padding=2)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5, padding=2)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(128*5*5, 31)


    def forward(self, x_in):

        # x is [bs, 1, 100, 100]
        x = xin + F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x_in)))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2) 
        # x is [bs, 32, 50, 50]
        x = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 5) 
        # x is [bs, 32, 10, 10]
        x = F.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(x)))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2) 
        # x is [bs, 64, 5, 5]
        x = x.view(-1, 128*5*5 ) # flatten
        x = F.relu(self.fc(x))
        return x
```

I'm just looking for general lines to take when this happens: more layers, less layers, transform.normalize on the data_loader, no padding, etc? Or maybe just increase the epochs ?